# Enable / Disable kendo ui drop down list using AngularJS ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, internet-explorer-9

I am unable to get the following example working in IE9. The drop down list does not enable or disable.

Using AngularJS v1.2.22 and Kendo UI v2014.2.903

Any help would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div kendo-drop-down-list k-data-source="names" ng-model="selected" ng-disabled="disabled">
</div> 
<label>ng-disable 
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="disabled" /> 
</label> 
<div kendo-drop-down-list k-data-source="names" ng-model="selected" k-enable="enabled">
</div> 
<label>k-enable 
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="enabled" /> 
</label> 
<pre>DISABLED: {{disabled}} ENABLED: {{enabled}}</pre>
```

JS:

```
$scope.names = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'];
$scope.enabled = true;
```

Comment: ng-disabled="disabled" is what you have on your markup, but $scope.enabled = true is what you have in your code

Comment: $scope.disabled = true; could also be in the js code, it is not required as the model value will be initialised when the check box is clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kendo's Dropdown List and Combobox *does seem to have trouble binding to ng-disabled* in IE9.

I have a workaround. Details are [here](http://www.gerardsetho.net/2014/11/kendo-angular-ie9-big-mess.html). Complete with Plunker code.

Basically,

1. you have to manually watch for whatever is inside the `ng-disabled` attribute yourself.
2. Then call the `enable()` function of Kendo's Combobox yourself. Dropdown Lists should work similarly.

hth

Comment: This works perfect. Unfortunately I cannot get this to work for the Kendo date picker.  Their controls seem to behave differently.

Answer (score 4):

For those coming on this page after 2015, Kendo added the custom attributes `k-ng-disabled` and `k-ng-readonly`, as described here:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#state-changes